# Standard fact about iterated forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm studying Laver's proof of the consistency of Borel's conjecture and he says that the following is a standard fact about iterated forcing:

---

> Define $\mathbb{P}^{\alpha \beta}$ as the set of all functions $f$ with domain $[\alpha, \beta)$ such that $1_{\alpha} \cup f \in \mathbb{P}_{\beta}$  and order $\mathbb{P}^{\alpha \beta}$ in $\mathfrak{M}[G_{\alpha}]$ with: 
>   $f \le g \longleftrightarrow (\exists p \in G_{\alpha}) p \cup f \le p\cup g$
>   Let $G_{\beta}$ be generic over $\mathbb{P}_{\beta}$, then $\mathfrak{M}[G_{\beta}] = \mathfrak{M}[G_{\alpha}][G^{\alpha \beta}]$ where $G^{\alpha \beta}$ is $\mathfrak{M}[G_{\alpha}]\text{-generic}$ over $\mathbb{P}^{\alpha \beta}$.

---

My thoughts:
 
I tried to prove $G_{\beta} = G_{\alpha} * G^{\alpha \beta}$ and that $G^{\alpha \beta} = G^{\beta}|_{[\alpha, \beta)}$ but i failed  because $G^{\alpha \beta}$ is so random. I would be really glad if someone pointed me in the right direction.

---

Edit I: The definitions that i forgot:
$G_{\alpha} = G_{\beta} |_{\alpha}$ and $1_{\alpha}$ is the canonical name for the greatest element of $\mathbb{P}_{\alpha}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\beta}$ is the $\beta\text{-th}$ stage iteration of Laver forcing.

Comment: This is a fairly standard fact for iterations. But I agree, it can be tricky to figure out how to prove these things when you're just starting with forcing. The easiest way is to define the partial order of $\Bbb P_\alpha\ast\Bbb P^{\alpha\beta}$ and show it is isomorphic to $\Bbb P_\beta$, and that should do *most* of the job for you. The rest is done by noting that the isomorphism is in fact the identity on $\Bbb P_\alpha\ast\{1_{\alpha\beta}\}$.

Comment: Oh right then by the two-step iteration lemma we are done, right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.